# Expect script to execute command, exit remote machine , print output and execute remaining script?

Tags: expect

I'm writing an expect script that executes a command on remote machine. I need to execute the command, take output , exit and print the output and also execute remaining script. Here is the script which I have written so far-

```
       #!/usr/bin/expect -f

       set user root
       set host xxxx
       set password  password
       set cmd  ls
       set timeout -1

       spawn ssh  $user@$host
       expect {
       "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/\\\[fingerprint\\\])?"
       {send "yes\n";exp_continue}
       "password:"
       {send "$password\n";exp_continue}
       "\\>"
       {send "$cmd\n"}
       -----------
       Need to print of cmd here
       -----------
       # disconnect
       ----------
       Exit remote machine
       {send  "exit\n"}
       expect eof
       -----------
       ---------
       Remaining code
       ---------
       }
       interact
```

Question is I am not able to get back to my expect script after executing command in remote machine.

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: I am not able to get back to my expect script after executing command in remote machine. I loose my script

Comment: please post a [repro]

Answer (score 0):

You've got all the program's functionality in one giant expect statement. It needs to be refactored so the program flow can be more linear.

```
set prompt {> ?$}       ;# adjust as required

spawn ssh  $user@$host
expect {
    "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/\\\[fingerprint\\\])?"
    {send "yes\n";exp_continue}

    "password:"
    {send "$password\n";exp_continue}

    -re $prompt
}

send "$cmd\r"
# Need to print of cmd here     -- what do you mean??
expect -re $prompt

send  "exit\r"
expect eof

# -- Now, you can execute the
# Remaining code
```